# Issue with CMQuaternion while try to get Euler angles

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, core-motion

in my app I would like to rotate the 3D model in 3 dimensions using the iPhone rotation. So my current method looks like this:

```
- (void)deviceMotionDataReceived:(CMDeviceMotion *)motion {

    CMQuaternion quat = motion.attitude.quaternion;

    NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f z:%f w%f", quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w);

    double myPitch = atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z);
    double myRoll = atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z);
    double myYaw = asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z);

     NSLog(@"pitch:%f roll:%f yaw:%f", myPitch, myRoll, myYaw);

}
```

Everything looks good - the pitch, roll accept rotation on 360 degrees, but when I change the yaw - the pitch/roll rotates to 180 degrees when yaw is ~90/-90 degrees. How can I get correct pitch/roll angles in all yaw bounds? Thx in advance!